# ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Grid Hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a simple kendo grid that i need to modify. When you click on a row it should display the table data in a hierarchical-like fashion.

My current grid:

```
@if (Model.Attributes != null && Model.Attributes.Any())
    {
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AttributeModel>()
            .BindTo(Model.Attributes)
            .Name("AttributesGrid")
            .Height(800)
            .Scrollable()
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(attribute => attribute.Code).Title("Code");
                columns.Bound(attribute => attribute.ProfessionCode).Title("Proffesion code");
            })
        )
    }
```

Models:

```
public class AttributeModel
{        
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    public string Code { get; set; }
            
    public string ProfessionCode { get; set; }
    
    public List<AttributeValueModel> AttributeValues { get; set; }
}

public class AttributeValueModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public long AttributeId { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

So when the row gets expanded (or when you click on a row) it should show 'Value' & 'IsDefault' properties from AttributeValueModel in a hierarchical-like fashion. How can i achieve that?

P.S. i dont need to send a request to some action/controller to get that data because all data is already loaded and available through @Model object. That's why there is no 'DataSource' function on kendo grid.

Comment: Have you seen the Kendo demo? https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding DetailTemplate

```
.DetailTemplate(attributeModel =>
 {
     return Html.Kendo().Grid<AttributeValueModel>()
            .Name("attributeValues_" + Guid.NewGuid())
            .BindTo(attributeModel.AttributeValues)
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                 columns.Bound(attributeValue => attributeValue.Value).Title("Value");
                 columns.Bound(attributeValue => attributeValue.IsDefault).Title("Is default");
            });
 })
```

The full Kendo grid looks like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<AttributeModel>()
            .BindTo(Model.Attributes)
            .Name("AttributesGrid")
            .Height(800)
            .Scrollable()
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(attribute => attribute.Code).Title("Code");
                columns.Bound(attribute => attribute.ProfessionCode).Title("Proffesion code");
            })
            .DetailTemplate(attributeModel =>
            {
                return Html.Kendo().Grid<AttributeValueModel>()
                    .Name("attributeValues_" + Guid.NewGuid())
                    .BindTo(attributeModel.AttributeValues)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                         columns.Bound(attributeValue => attributeValue.Value).Title("Value");
                         columns.Bound(attributeValue => attributeValue.IsDefault).Title("Is default");
                    });
             })
        )
```

**Do not add '**`.ToClientTemplate()`**' function.**